# git merging latest commits from master back into branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In my repository I have a branch named "UI-Enhancements". This branch started off the main branch after a check in on the 25/02/2015. See outlined check in below.

[image]

Since the branching of the code on the 25/02/2015 I have done several check ins and pushes in my master branch. See the check ins on my master branch below and note the times.

[image]

Before continuing work in my UI-Enhancements branch I would like to merge all my latest commits in my master branch into my UI-Enhancements branch.

I am using tortoise git as my client. I am unsure how to do this. I have tried to go to my UI-Enhancements branch and have selected git synch with my local branch as UI-Enhancements and my remote branch as master but I don't think that is the right way to do it because I get the following error...

[image]

I have tried to go to my UI-Enhancements branch and Pull from the master branch but it just says that everything is up to date.

Can someone help me with what I need to do please? Please try and make the answers specific to TortoiseGit since this is the client I am using. As an FYI the version of TortoiseGit I am using is 1.8.11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clue how to do this in TortoiseGit, but the command line is dead easy:

```
git checkout 1.0.0-UI-ENHANCEMENTS
git rebase master
```

This will checkout the current `master` branch and replay all your commits done in `1.0.0-UI-ENHANCEMENTS` on top of the *current state* of `master`.

Please note that after the `rebase` you have to `git push -f origin 1.0.0-UI-ENHANCEMENTS` because of the rebasing process.

Have a further read about rebasing in the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and in the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: I'd recommend a rebase as well, unless other people are also working off of `1.0.0-UI-ENHANCEMENTS`.

Comment: @jcm: Yes, absolutely. I'm sure I've read the reasoning dozens of times (and I know that and understand it) but cannot find a link that explains it in detail why. It would be a good think to have a resource somewhere that could be linked as the **push-force-downsides-on-shared-repositories**-disclaimer here...

Comment: Thanks guys. I do have git bash so I can try this. Luckily the commits I will be merging from master back into the UI-Enhancements branch are not conflicting but what if they were? How would this command decide to resolve the conflicts?

Comment: @Richie: If there are any conflicts that could not be automatically resolved, rebasing will stop on this commit and you have to resolve the conflicts manually, just like you usually do.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer to this question has been accepted as the asnwer to this and it was the correct asnwer. For a tortoise git translation here is how you can do what was described in the accepted answer.

Here is how to check out...

[image]

Here is how to rebase from the remote master branch.
[image]